# How to keep DataFrame index after getting BOW in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am calling BOW function in Python

but after I do so the index of the dataframe changes to 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

My Original Data Fram df_reps_all looks like this

```
df_reps_all
Out[20]: 
                                                 RepText
RepID                                                   
26     C0334227 C0007634 C0032226 C0032225 C0040300 C...
137    C0557854 C0028429 C0028429 C0817096 C0817096 C...
148    C0020538 C0021641 C0021641 C0021641 C0011854 C...
188    C0151908 C1123023 C0496955 C0496955 C0496955 C...
206    C0578150 C0022646 C0010294 C0010294 C0018787 C...
                                                 ...
59462  C0004057 C0004057 C0004057 C0039225 C0039225 C...
59619  C0040961 C2004489 C0003483 C0003483 C0003501 C...
59623  C0024299 C0024299 C0024299 C0544452 C0027651 C...
59646  C0421451 C0421451 C0005615 C0009253 C0557854 C...
59648  C0421451 C0421451 C0005615 C0009253 C0557854 C...

[1996 rows x 1 columns]
```

Look at the Index it is 26, 137, 148, etc.

after calling BOW for this the RepText.

I get index in 0, 1, 2, 3,

```
df_BOW
Out[29]: 
      c0000294  c0000503  c0000545  ...  c4721505  c4721555  c4759703
0            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
1            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
2            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
3            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
4            0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
1991         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
1992         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
1993         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
1994         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0
1995         0         0         0  ...         0         0         0

[1996 rows x 11459 columns]
```

How can I keep the same index in the BOW function?

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pyodbc 
import datetime



def BOW(df):
    CountVec = CountVectorizer() 
    Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
    cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(),columns=CountVec.get_feature_names())
    return cv_dataframe
    

ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=DELLG3;Database=R3;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

conn = pyodbc.connect(ConnectionString)


df_reps_all = pd.read_sql("EXEC GetReps_Idea15"  , conn)

 
df_reps_all.set_index("RepID", inplace=True)

df_BOW = BOW(df_reps_all["RepText"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the old index, then perform `BOW` and then put it back:

```
...
# save the old index
old_index = df_reps_all.RepID
df_reps_all = df_reps_all.set_index("RepID")

# perform BOW
df_BOW = BOW(df_reps_all["RepText"])

# put the old index back
df_BOW.index = old_index
```